# Is there any public/global variable in java?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that uses java.util.Scanner to take user input. This will be used in multiple methods...

Is it possible to..

```
public class Main {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          ...
          String mainInput = input.nextLine();
          ...
       }

    private static void add(){
          ...
          String addInput = input.nextLine();
          ...
       }
}
```

Or will I have to have **Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);** In both
// methods.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          ...
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          String mainInput = input.nextLine();
          ...
       }

    private static void add(){
          ...
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          String addInput = input.nextLine();
          ...
       }
}
```

I plan to have this in 3-4 other methods.

EDIT:

In my program I followed the first. I receive an error: **Non-static field ‘input’ cannot be referenced from a static context**

ANSWERED!

```
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: This is certainly possible.

Comment: Or option 3) let `add()` method accept Scanner as argument like `private static void add(Scanner sc){... String addInput = sc.nextLine(); ...}`, so I could create it once in main method and pass it to `add` method like `main... { Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); ... add(input); ...}`.

Comment: @luk2302 is it possible to create `static object` of a class like static variable? for instance `Scanner static sc = new Scanner(...)` _it doesn't work anyway!_....

Comment: @XO56 Could you clarify what you mean by "static object" and "static variable"? BTW field modifiers (like static, private, volatile, etc..) come *before* declared *type* so instead of `Scanner static sc` it should be `static Scanner sc`.

Comment: @Pshemo By static variable i meant global variable in the main class. However `Static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);` gives compiler error! btw what do you think about the first code snippet of the OP.

Comment: "However `Static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);` gives compiler error" that is because there is a typo in `static`. Java is case sensitive so `Static` != `static`. Regarding 1st vs 2nd approach, IMO 1st is better since it doesn't create multiple Scanners to handle `System.io` which at some point (by mistake or by applying IDE suggestion) someone later may decide to close which will also close `System.io` preventing it being used in rest of application (like when we again will want to use `add()` method). BUT I would probably use 3rd option from my first comment.

Comment: Creating multiple Scanner's on System.in does have the possibility of causing a problem. Closing a Scanner on System.in guarantees problems if you close it too early.

Comment: @Pshemo Thank you very much! :) Sometimes a little push is very important!.... for last 2 days i was wondering this problem! didn't even know what to ask! 

Comment: @Pshemo Thank you so much! I got it to work. so am I right in saying when I need a public variable I use the 'static' keyword?

Comment: @A'notherUser `public` and `static` modifiers are unrelated/responsible for different things. `public` is *visibility* modifier (so you could decide who will have access to it), making field `static` in Java means that member will belong to a class, not instance (since you seem not familiar with those concepts please read about them from tutorials as they are core of the language - assuming you want to learn it). Anyway people tend to avoid `static` fields when possible. They mainly ware used to store constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the input right away the first method would be my way to go.